# the minimum of a differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I'm trying to prove the following claim:

$f:\left[p,q\right]\:\to\mathbb R,\ f$ is differentiable at $p$ and $p$ is a minimum of $f$. prove or disprove: $f'(p) \ge  0$.

When I draw a graph, it seemed obvious that the claim is true. the minimum is at the left edge of the function, so the function must go up afterwards.
but as I know, the derivative at minimum / maximum equals to $0$. So why am I being asked about $f'(p) \ge  0$ ?

Tryed to prove using rolle theorem, but I don't know if the function is differentiable at $q$ (and maybe it isn't).

Comment: Because you could have $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x$.

Comment: By the way, Rolle's theorem does not require differentiability at the extremal points (just continuity), but in return it tells nothing about them.

Comment: is $f:\:\left[0,1\right]\:→\:R\:$ with $f(x) = x$ a counter-example? if so, i can't see why.

Comment: There is a technical caveat here: if $f$ is only defined on $[p,q]$, then $f$ can't be differentiable in the usual sense at $p$, because the definition of differentiable requires $f$ to be defined in a neighbourhood of $p$.   But perhaps what is meant is that it is differentiable from the right at $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f'(p) = \lim_{x \to p \\ x > p} \frac{\overbrace{f(x) - f(p)}^{\ge 0}}{\underbrace{x-p}_{\ge 0}} \ge 0$$

Comment: what if we have $x\to p^-$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan $f$ is only defined on $[p,q]$. I presume that by "differentiable" at $p$, OP means "differentiable to the right" at $p$.

Comment: Opps, I forgot it. Thanks

Comment: I only miss an argument that the limit of a non-negative function is non-negative.

Comment: This might work: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/977068/86776